# $3\times3$ matrix that has $\text{col}(A) = \text{Null}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Looking to get some guidance in the following proof. I am trying to find a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ such that the $\text{col}(A)=\text{Null}(A)$

I am thinking that I need to use the rank + nullity theorem. I know that $\text{rank}(A) + \text{nullity}(A) = n$ and rank is the amount of leading 1's in a matrix when brought into row echelon form. I am trying to wrap my head around this question, my hypothesis is that this would not be possible by the rank + nullity theorem but I am not quite sure how to show this.

Comment: By $col(A)$ do you mean the column space of the matrix?

Comment: If that was true then the dimension of the domain would need to be even.

Comment: yes the column space of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column space of $A$ and the null space of $A$ were the same, then their dimensions would be equal, i.e. $rank(A) = nullity(A)$. But then $rank(A)+nullity(A)$ would be even, but the rank-nullity theorem states this sum is $3$, a contradiction.

Comment: alright thank you very much for this proof, is this the entire proof?